# How to exchange data between Python and Rust with zero copy?

Tags: python, rust, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am tring to bring my heavy calculation to Rust form Python, and get the result in Python from Rust. Cross different language may cause copy, I use `Polars-DataFrame` or `Arrow` as the datatype in Rust. Is there some method could achieve exchange data with zero copy between these two languages?

Comment: You may need a C/C++ interface to create a Python object wrapper for your data type.  That's basically what numpy does.  It's all native C data structures with wrappers.

Comment: You should just be able to use PyO3 to create a [python class in Rust code](https://pyo3.rs/v0.16.2/class.html), so the data is stored however you'd like to do it in Rust and you provide a Python API to access it.

Comment: Using Pyo3 to creating a python class is great,but when the data done calculation is Rust , it seems like still need `copy` to python env?

Comment: Does this article help? https://medium.com/@niklas.molin/0-copy-you-pyarrow-array-to-rust-23b138cb5bf2

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you！！

Comment: that article explains how to zero-copy pass structs from python to rust, but not the other way round. Did you find out how to do that?